# Generic Writer Fanout of file geodatabase

Tags: fme-form

I would like to fanout file geodatabase on an specific attribute by using generic writer with Dynamic schema. I know how to do this when not using Generic Writer, so I assumed that principle will be the same. What I get now are fanout folders comprising of fanout fgdbs, rather than only fanout fgdbs. I.e. in the Fanout Directory are folders (FanoutPrefix_AttributeTOFanoutOn) and in those folders are fgdbs (BaseFilename_AttributeToFanoutOn).

So, I do not need to have fanout fgdb to be placed in the additional folders created when doing fanout, only to be placed in the Fanout Directory as defined in Navigator.